# pm2 cannot create multiple instances of expressjs - EADDRINUSE port in use error

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I'm trying to use pm2 process manager with ExpressJS application. The first instance runs and works normally but others continuously crashes with EADDRINUSE and runs again and again. So I'm wondering what am I doing wrong?

I run pm2 with next command:

```
pm2 start process.json
```

process.json config file for pm2 looks like:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "clinical-trials",
      "script": "./bin/www",
      "instances": 0,
      "env": {
        "PORT" : 4000,
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "env_production": {
        "PORT": 4444,
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      },
      "env_local": {
        "PORT" : 4000,
        "NODE_ENV": "local"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Express `./bin/www` contains next code:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || app.locals.config.port);
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

In the example folder of PM2 repo they have child process that listens on 8000 port:
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/examples/child.js
and config file that runs 4 instances:
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/master/examples/apps/all-pm2.json

Comment: Each port can be used only by single instance.

Comment: Did you set `instances` field of `process.json` to 0 intentionally?

Comment: you mean: execute `pm2 start process.json` start normally and then exeucute `pm2 start process.json --env local` got EADDRINUSE, right?

Comment: Are you running `pm2 start process.json` twice? Try running it without the json config `pm2 start ./bin/www -i 2` to see if it works.

Comment: Guys, `instances` are set to 0 in order to make pm2 run 1 instance per CPU. I start the process once with command `pm2 start process.json` and it creates only one app instance. Other instances falls with EADDRINUSE.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in that pm2 tried to run instances in fork mode instead of cluster. To fix the problem I had to add `"exec_mode": cluster` to `process.json` file. :

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "clinical-trials",
      "script": "./bin/www",
      "instances": 0,
      "exec_mode": "cluster",
      "env": {
        "PORT" : 4000,
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "env_production": {
        "PORT": 4444,
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      },
      "env_local": {
        "PORT" : 4000,
        "NODE_ENV": "local"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I spent hours on this and your answer pointed me to the cluster documentation which discusses the -i max arguments that you can pass to pm2 start.  More info here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/ .